# jax-ws stream for large SOAP Response

Tags: jax-ws

I have a requirment to provide the SOAP response in Stream as the soap resoponse is pretty big and might cause Outofmemory exception. Say I have an Entity consists of 20 field and no of records are around 10lakh. Anybody have any idea how to do it..???

```
public class ReportResponse{

private String name;
private String address;
private String number;

}


  @WebService
  @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
  @SchemaValidation(handler = SchemaValidationCustomErrorHandler.class)
  public class MyServiceEndpoint {

 @Resource
private final ReportDispatcher dispatcher;

@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

@WebMethod(operationName = "GetReport")
    public List<ReportResponse> getReport()
        throws GenericSoapFault {

    final MessageContext messageContext = this.wsContext.getMessageContext();
     final SAXParseException errorException = (SAXParseException)      messageContext.get(SchemaValidationCustomErrorHandler.ERROR);
    final SAXParseException fatalErrorException = (SAXParseException) messageContext.get(SchemaValidationCustomErrorHandler.FATAL_ERROR);

    String errorMessage = null;

    if (errorException != null) {
        errorMessage = errorException.getMessage();
    } else if (fatalErrorException != null) {
        errorMessage = fatalErrorException.getMessage();
    }

    if (errorMessage != null) {
        if (checkIfDateRangeError(errorMessage)) {
            responseBuilder.withException(new ExceptionBuilder().withInvalidDatesError().build());
            return responseBuilder.build();
        }
        throw new GenericSoapFault(errorMessage);

    }

    return this.dispatcher.generateReport();

  }



}
```

here generateReport function provide result about few lakhs. For which I need to use Streeaming... I found StreamingDataHandler class... but not sure how to use it.

Comment: Can you improve the description of the problem or question? Could you provide more detail? If you have any code.

Comment: updated...few parts of my code!!